# Oracle query for time difference in seconds

Tags: sql, oracle

I am looking for a query to find the gap between two time fields.

Table `A` and table `B` in both `COL3` contain time value. `8:13:54`.  `COL3` Is a Char field.

Table `B` also having same fields.  I Want to query on the following conditions.

```
A.COL1 = B.COL1 and 
A.COL2 = B.COL2 and 
(COL3 in a should equal to + / - 120 secs of COL B).
```

I tried  to use `TO_DATE`, but its not working out.  How can i achieve this?

This works for me. Thanks.

SELECT A.*, B.*
FROM A, B
WHERE A.COL1 = B.COL1
AND A.COL2 = B.COL2
AND ( TO_DATE(B.COL3,'hh:mi:ss') = (TO_DATE(B.COL3,'hh:mi:ss') + (120/(24*60*60)))
      OR TO_DATE(B.COL3,'hh:mi:ss') = (TO_DATE(B.COL3,'hh:mi:ss') - (120/(24*60*60))) )

Comment: What is the data type of `col3`?  `time` is not a valid data type in Oracle.  Do you have an `interval`?  A `date`?  A `varchar2` in (hopefully) a single format?

Answer (score 15):

Something like this:

```
select (laterDate - earlierDate) * 24 * 60 * 60 seconds
from etc
```

In oracle, dates are numbers.  Each integer increment represents one calendar day.

Comment: I have to disagree.  In Oracle, dates are of type DATE.  Differences between dates (of type DATE) are expressed as number of days (NUMBER datatype).  So, something like "to_date('01/01/2013','MM/DD/YYYY') - to_date('12/31/2012','MM/DD/YYYY')" will return a numeric 1, meaning the difference is 1 day.

Comment: Yes you are right Mark.The below query works for me                 SELECT A., B. FROM A, B WHERE A.COL1 = B.COL1 AND A.COL2 = B.COL2 AND ( TO_DATE(B.COL3,'hh:mi:ss') = (TO_DATE(B.COL3,'hh:mi:ss') + (120/(24*60*60))) OR TO_DATE(B.COL3,'hh:mi:ss') = (TO_DATE(B.COL3,'hh:mi:ss') - (120/(24*60*60))) )